# A shell tool to "tablify" input data

Tags: shell

A long time ago I remember using a command that makes its input into a nicely formatted table.

For example, for this input,

```
apple 1 100
orange 20 19
pineapple 1000 87
avocado 4 30
```

The output will be similar to this:

```
apple     1    100
orange    20   19
pineapple 1000 87
avocado   4    30
```

I'd like to know the name of this tool.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Use `column -t`. [**column**](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/column.1.html) is part of [util-linux](https://www.kernel.org/pub/linux/utils/util-linux/).

```
$ column -t <<END
> apple 1 100
> orange 20 19
> pineapple 1000 87
> avocado 4 30
> END
apple      1     100
orange     20    19
pineapple  1000  87
avocado    4     30
```

Comment: I like the man page: "**columnate** lists". Similar to "tablify".

Answer (score 0):

**`awk` solution that deals with stdin**

Since `column` is not POSIX, maybe this is:

```
mycolumn() (
  file="${1:--}"
  if [ "$file" = - ]; then
    file="$(mktemp)"
    cat >"${file}"
  fi
  awk '
  FNR == 1 { if (NR == FNR) next }
  NR == FNR {
    for (i = 1; i <= NF; i++) {
      l = length($i)
      if (w[i] < l)
        w[i] = l
    }
    next
  }
  {
    for (i = 1; i <= NF; i++)
      printf "%*s", w[i] + (i > 1 ? 1 : 0), $i
    print ""
  }
  ' "$file" "$file"
  if [ "$file" = - ]; then
    rm "$file"
  fi
)
```

Test:

```
printf '12 1234 1
12345678 1 123
1234 123456 123456
' > file
```

Test commands:

```
mycolumn file
mycolumn <file
mycolumn - <file
```

Output for all:

```
      12   1234      1
12345678      1    123
    1234 123456 123456
```

See also:

- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14095011/using-awk-to-align-columns-in-text-file
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28544105/awk-go-through-the-file-twice-doing-different-tasks

Answer (score 0):

For relatively small files, (where the length in bytes is less than `getconf ARG_MAX`), and the input sizes are more or less known, (let's say no fruit name is more than 18 letters long), `printf` can be useful, here's a `bash` example:

```
 printf '%-20s %5s %5s\n' $(<file.txt)
```

Output:

```
apple                    1   100
orange                  20    19
pineapple             1000    87
avocado                  4    30
```

Note how the numbers are *right* justified.