# reformatting output with aligned columns

Tags: text-processing

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [A shell tool to “tablify” input data](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/17664/a-shell-tool-to-tablify-input-data)

I have a program outputting something like this:

```
abc   defgh   ijklm
nopqr   stu  vw
xyza bcde   fghi
```

which I'd like to clean up to get something like this:

```
abc    defgh  ijklm
nopqr  stu    vw
xyza   bcde   fghi
```

I looked at `column`, `tr` and `sed` without seeing anything; do any of those work? Is there another tool I can use?

Answer (score 40, accepted):

`column -t file` seems the way to go.